# Stochastic modelling for rickshaw rides

Tags: syntax-error, stochastic-process

How can I solve this problem?

i want my code not error and please provide easy to understand explanations. this is about stochastic models rickshaw rides.

[image]

[image]

```
from scipy.stats import poisson

#Parameter
lamda = 2 #rata-rata turis yang datang per 2 menit
#Menghitung probabilitas untuk jumlah turis yang berbeda
turis = [0,1, 2,3,4]
bobot = poisson.pmf(turis, lamda)
#menghitung bobot untuk setiap jumlah turis
bobot[-1] =1-sum(bobot[:-1]) 
bobot

#Matrix Makrov (Prob Transisi)
p[0,:]=bobot
p[1,:]=bobot
p[2,:]=bobot
p[3,1:]=bobot[:-1]
p[3,-1:]=bobot[-2:]
p[4,:]=bobo
p
```

Comment: You did not post complete code. Where is the variable p defined?